# Overwrite allWrap if checkbox in page page options is checked in menu

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I like to overwrite a allWrap option in a typoscript menu definition if a checkbox in the page options is checked. The following pages should be highlighted, so i need to add an extra css class to the list tag.

In my page options i have an boolean named `tx_mask_highlight_nav`.

So in my fluid template i have access with `{page.tx_mask_highlight_nav}`.

But i need this in my typoscript menu definition.

My current approach looks like this:

```
lib.menu_main = COA
lib.menu_main {
  10 = HMENU
  10 {
    entryLevel = 0
    wrap = |

    1 = TMENU
    1 {
      expAll = 1
      NO.allWrap = <li>|</li>
      NO.ATagTitle.field = abstract // description // title

      NO.allWrap.override = <li class="menu-item--bold">|</li>
      NO.allWrap.override.if {
        isTrue.data = page:tx_mask_highlight_nav
      }

      ACT = 1
      ACT.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="active">|</li>
      ACT.ATagTitle.field = abstract // description // title

      IFSUB = 1
      IFSUB.wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>
      IFSUB.ATagTitle.field = abstract // description // title

      ACTIFSUB = 1
      ACTIFSUB.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="active">|</li>
      ACTIFSUB.ATagTitle.field = abstract // description // title
    }

    1 {
      wrap = <ul class="dropdown menu menu--main" data-dropdown-menu>|</ul>
    }

    2 < .1
    2 {
      wrap = <ul class="menu vertical">|</ul>
    }

    3 < .2
    4 < .3
    5 < .4
  }
}
```

I've tried several other things, for example this:

```
NO.allWrap.override = <li class="menu-item--bold">|</li>
No.allWrap.override.if {
    value = page:tx_mask_highlight_nav
    equals = 1
}
```

But it does not work. Maybe i have no access to `page:tx_mask_highlight_nav`?

Would be really thankful for your help!

Comment: Try `NO.allWrap.override.if.isTrue.field = tx_mask_highlight_nav`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace data with field. Use `NO.allWrap.override.if.isTrue.field = tx_mask_highlight_nav`

Full TypoScript

```
lib.menu_main = COA
lib.menu_main {
  10 = HMENU
  10 {
    entryLevel = 0
    wrap = |

    1 = TMENU
    1 {
      expAll = 1
      NO.allWrap = <li>|</li>
      NO.ATagTitle.field = abstract // description // title

      NO.allWrap.override = <li class="menu-item--bold">|</li>
      NO.allWrap.override.if.isTrue.field = tx_mask_highlight_nav

      ACT = 1
      ACT.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="active">|</li>
      ACT.ATagTitle.field = abstract // description // title

      IFSUB = 1
      IFSUB.wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>
      IFSUB.ATagTitle.field = abstract // description // title

      ACTIFSUB = 1
      ACTIFSUB.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="active">|</li>
      ACTIFSUB.ATagTitle.field = abstract // description // title
    }

    1 {
      wrap = <ul class="dropdown menu menu--main" data-dropdown-menu>|</ul>
    }

    2 < .1
    2 {
      wrap = <ul class="menu vertical">|</ul>
    }

    3 < .2
    4 < .3
    5 < .4
  }
}
```